# Is there a way to redirect to an errorPage without mentioning that page in the jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have an `errorPage.jsp` in which I have included

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" import="java.io.*"%>
```

but in my code I can not find any page that has

```
<%@ page errorPage="errorPage.jsp" %>
```

defined inside of it. Still if any exception is thrown anywhere, `errorPage.jsp` is shown.

Any ideas how it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could check your `web.xml` file for the tag called `error-page`. For further reference, feel free to check this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1017571)

Comment: In my web.xml there are two handlers defined. One for pageNotFound and the other for an uncaught Exception. Both these finally return a very different jsp named 'httpError'. I can't even find a controller in which i hoped that some method might be returning the errorPage.jsp

       <error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
  <location>/app/webExceptionHandler/uncaughtException</location>
 </error-page>

  <error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/app/webExceptionHandler/pageNotFound</location>
 </error-page>

Comment: hmmm, strange indeed you afaik it should be either defined in the `JSP` as you know it. And the other way, is to use the `error-page` tag. And also, I found it strange that the `location` tag refer to a non `jsp` or `html` page. Did you changed the value of the `location` tag before post it in here?

Comment: My bad, the httpError was actually set to errorPage via tiles.xml.

Comment: the location tag referred internally to a controller with RequestMapping = "/webExceptionHandler" and the method had RequestMapping = "/uncaughtException". This method returned "httpError" whose mapping internally in tiles.xml was done as: 

<definition name="httpError" extends="hfTemplate">
  <put-attribute name="title" value="Error" />
  <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/errorPage.jsp" />
 </definition>

Comment: ahh, then I guess it would be better for you to answer your own question and the mark it as the accepted answer.